# Skipping empty string with JSONEncoders swift

Tags: swift, codable

I a codable serialization extension which I use to turn my Codable struct to dictionaries, the problem I am facing is strings. I get string value from my UITextField at at times this value could be empty and as a result an empty string is decoded. How can I return nil if the value is an empty string.

```
extension Encodable {
    var requestDictionary: [String: Any]? {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        encoder.keyEncodingStrategy = .convertToSnakeCase
        guard let data = try? encoder.encode(self) else { return nil }
        
        
        return (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)).flatMap { $0 as? [String: Any] }
    }
}
```

if I have a Struct

```
let example = Exa(age: 10, name: "")
let dict = example.requestDictionary
print(dict)
```

I want it to just print `["age": 10]` and return nil for the empty string

Comment: fix that in `Exa` init? `self.name = name.isEmpty ? nil : name`. By the way, why do you encode to JSON and then decode it again into a dictionary?

Comment: Because I am using a codable object and making an API call with dictionary parameters.

Comment: you cant customize inside a general extension so you have to make it inside the struct itself

Comment: Yeah, @Sh_Khan you can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement your own `String` encoding method extending `KeyedEncodingContainer`:

```
extension KeyedEncodingContainer {
    mutating func encode(_ value: String, forKey key: K) throws {
        guard !value.isEmpty else { return }
        try encodeIfPresent(value, forKey: key)
    }
}
```

---

Btw your request dictionary can be simplified as:

```
extension Encodable {
    var dictionary: [String: Any]? {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        encoder.keyEncodingStrategy = .convertToSnakeCase
        return try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: encoder.encode(self)) as? [String: Any]
    }
}
```

---

Playground testing:

```
struct Exa: Encodable {
    let age: Int
    let name: String
}
```

---

```
let example = Exa(age: 10, name: "")
let dict = example.dictionary!
print(dict)  // "["age": 10]\n"
```

Comment: This fails when a String property is not empty, e.g. `let example = Exa(age: 10, name: "Leo")`. The func `encode` keeps calling itself in an infinite loop.

Comment: @MarioHuizinga that is really weird. Not sure why would it cause a loop.

Comment: I have tried exactly your example on Playground, just changing the name. Did you try that? It seems that the `try encode(value, forKey: key)` statement calls itself again (and again).

Comment: @MarioHuizinga yes I did notice that

Comment: I fixed your solution by replacing `try encode` with `try encodeIfPresent`. This prevents the recursion. It works great now, thanks for this idea. I have submitted an Edit on your answer.

Comment: That’s weird considering that the value is always present and it doesn’t happen with the empty string. Thanks anyway

Comment: Instead of using `JSONEncoder().encode(example)`, is there anyway to create a function on a `JSONEncoder` that does this functionality? So instead you can do `JSONEncoder().encodeIfNotEmpty(example)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just another approach using a property wrapper to mark which properties could be skipped.

```
@propertyWrapper
struct SkipEmpty {
   var wrappedValue: String
}

extension SkipEmpty: Codable {
   init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
      let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
      self.wrappedValue = try container.decode(String.self)
   }

   func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
      // nothing to do here, see below
   }
}
```

But to actually skip, you'd also need to create a overload for the `KeyedEncodingContainer.encode` method for the `SkipEmpty` type:

```
extension KeyedEncodingContainer {
   mutating func encode(_ value: SkipEmpty, forKey key: K) throws {
      if !value.wrappedValue.isEmpty {
         try encode(value.wrappedValue, forKey: key) // encode the value here
      }
   }
}
```

You could possibly try to make it more generic, e.g. `SkipEmpty<T: Codable>` and provide another argument for the value to skip or a predicate, etc...

---

The usage is:

```
struct Exa: Encodable {
   var age: Int
   @SkipEmpty var name: String
}
```